# How to write RxJs Angular code into RxDart

Tags: angular, flutter, dart, rxjs, rxdart

How can i write the following RxJs Angular code in Flutter RxDart.

```
  callConcatMapPayload(apiPostData) {
of(...apiPostData) // here of() is creational operator from RxJs (Observable)
  .pipe(
    concatMap((params) =>
      this.controlService.apipostHttpRequest(
        params.url,
        params.headers,
        params.data
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((res) => {
    this.bindHiddenArray(res, apiPostData, this.multiapiindex);
    this.multiapiindex += 1;
  });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory glance at the docs for RxDart, I would guess this should work. You'll have to test it of course.

```ts
callConcatMapPayload(apiPostData){

  const s = fromIterable(apiPostData)
    .flatMap(({url, headers, data}) => fromFuture(
      this.controlService.apipostHttpRequest(url, headers, data)
    ))

  await for (let res in s) {
    this.bindHiddenArray(res, apiPostData, this.multiapiindex);
    this.multiapiindex += 1;
  }

}
```